# Trying to move away from nodeIntegration

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder, electron-webpack

I have an electron project that uses the nodeIntegration for a lack of understanding for while now. I am electron-webpack and electron-builder to build my project. It all works fine, but my main goal is to create a slim version of the app as a web service.

As a first step, I'd like to be able to run the current desktop version with nodeIntegration disabled. I now have the time to make some changes to the project, but it's quite difficult to find help, because often the tip is to just enable nodeIntegration, when some of these errors appear.

I have already moved node dependencies and ipc calls to the electron context bridge in my preload script.
I was hoping this would be enough to make evertything run again. But currently, when I start the project, I get a few errors, that I don't quite understand:

### Missing require()

My index.html contains the following scripts:

```
<script>require('module').globalPaths.push("C:/Development/my-app/node_modules")</script>    
<script>require("source-map-support/source-map-support.js").install()</script>
```

First of all, I don't even know where these are coming from.
Secondly this is of course not working, since I disabled the node integration.
I don't know how to fix this issue. Any require is of course creating problem. But the whole goal of this operation is to keep nodeIntegration disabled.

### Module is not defined

My renderer.js now starts with:

```
module.exports =
```

Which throws

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

How can I avoid these problems?